# Number of turns in a flat spiral-coil?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

Given that a flat-coil has $N$ turns of radius $r = R$ which varies between $R_1$, and $R_2$, what is the number of turns per unit length, that is differentiated w.r.t. $dr$?

My textbook says it’s $\frac{N \cdot dr}{R_1 - R_2}$, but I’m not sure I understand why.

Comment: Number of turns= number of turns per unit length * length $\equiv$ Total turns/total length * needed length $\equiv$ N/(R1-R2) * dr

Comment: Not sure how you can have a "flat coil" with rings all at the same radius

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean number of turns per unit radius-change. If so, in case
$$ \frac {dN}{d R} = \text {const} \tag 1,$$

then it follows that :

$$ \frac {dN}{d R} = \frac{\Delta N}{\Delta R}, \tag 2$$

Or ,

$$ dN = \frac{\Delta N d R}{\Delta R}, \tag 3 $$